# android studio use old java jdk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

For university we have to create an app based on JAVA SE 11 and run on android so we planned to use android studio.
Trying to do so I selected the jdk under Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployement -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK, which I think is what ure supposed to do to use Java 11.

Doing this I had to downgrade the Gradle Version of the Project to 5.0 as far as Im informed, which I did in the project settings, and here Im getting to the next problem which runs an error about

> Unresolved referenece: dependencyResolutionManagement

Not really knowing what to do I just deleted that block of code. which kinda works except that now there is the error of the AGP(Android Gradle Plugin) Version for which the gradle version is too low, but since we have to use that one, I have to downgrade the AGP version.

Trying to do so I changed the version of it in build.gradle.kts in
`id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false`
to 3.3.0 which only requires gradle 4.10.1 or higher.
Problem here: it cant find the Plugin anywhere.

> Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '3.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
> or`- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)

- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin marker 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:3.3.0')`

also Im using Android studio Giraffe, even saying requiring AGP 3.2.0 - is this an IDE thing?

my build.gradle (app) file:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication3"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication3"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.5")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

Comment: Can you post your full build.gradle?

Comment: @Marsroverr `// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "3.3.0" apply false
}`is the complete file where the error points too... but Android Studio creates a 2nd build.graddle file... want to see that one too?

Comment: Yea, send the app build.gradle too

Comment: @Marsroverr put it into the post :)

Answer (score 0):

Java Version:
Make sure you are using Java SE 11, as you mentioned. In Android Studio, you can set the JDK version by going to File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project SDK

Comment: I dont have that setting under Projekt, but isntead it tells me "JDK location was moved to Graddle Settings". and thats where I changed the JDK to the wanted JDK. Now there are the above mentioned errors occuring. :/

Comment: Update the Android Gradle plugin you can specify the plugin version in either the File > Project Structure > Project menu in Android Studio, or the top-level build.gradle.kts file. The plugin version applies to all modules built in that Android Studio project. The following example sets the plugin to version 8.1.0 from the build.gradle.kts file: plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false
}

Comment: I cant set it in the Project structures, because there is no menu... running ur code I also get some kotlin errors I cant comprehend and also my goal is to set it down to 3.3.0 ... and if I try it with changig the version to 3.3.0 it says it cant find the version...